# How to start use ROS with Robotino

Tags: ros, robotino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I´m new to use ROS, can you help me what´s the thinks that I need to install and how can do

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267412/how-to-start-use-ros-with-robotino/) by [Tania Osorio](https://answers.ros.org/users/31348/tania-osorio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install ROS following the official tutorial: http://www.ros.org/install/.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1